# upgraded the cordova and android, not able to hit google api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, google-maps, cordova-plugins

I have added the well defined csp,whitelist plugin,edited the config.xml properly still the issues exit.below one defines.

```
 Failed to load resource: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyAPI&sensor=true
```

Reference

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://maps.googleapis.com">
```

Config.xml

```
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-appavailability 0.4.2 "AppAvailability"
cordova-plugin-extension 1.1.4 "Cordova Plugin Extension"
cordova-plugin-googleplayservices 19.0.1 "Google Play Services for Android"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.2.0 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2-dev "Whitelist"
org.apache.cordova.device 0.3.0 "Device"
uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.LaunchNavigator 2.9.2 "Launch Navigator"
```

Comment: The whitelist plugin is not listed.. are you sure that you have installed correctly?
 `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`

Comment: @manzapanza i have updated my plugin, got missed while copying. now please help me on the mentioned issue.

Comment: have you tried removing and adding platform again

Comment: @ Prateek Rathore yes i have done that also..

Comment: Did you changed `MyAPI` parameter with your real api key?

Comment: Yes its working now.. only thing i have altered the csp meta tag...